# CloudFormation Stack resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, boto3

I am trying to receive Stack resources ARN information using boto3.
I tried to use:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.resource('cloudformation', 
  aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxx',
  aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxx')

response = client.list_stack_resources(
  StackName='ORG-ROLES')
```

I get "AttributeError: 'cloudformation.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'list_stack_resources'"
This Stack runs 9 resources, I want to get one resource ARN information.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: Change `boto3.resource` to `boto3.client`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up the [client-level](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html) and [resource-level](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html) APIs. You need to use one or the other. Here's an example of each.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name='xxxx', region_name='us-east-1')

STACK_NAME = 'ORG-ROLES'

# Use client-level API
client = session.client('cloudformation')
response = client.list_stack_resources(StackName=STACK_NAME)
print('Client API:', response['StackResourceSummaries'])

# Use resource-level API
resource = session.resource('cloudformation')
stack = resource.Stack(STACK_NAME)
print('Resource API:', list(stack.resource_summaries.all()))
```